# C++/Qt perform mouse click

Tags: c++, qt, mouse, qt5

I've started simply Qt5 / C++ project and I wish to control mouse (outside an application window) in some platform independent way.

I've figured out, that there is nice method:

```
QCursor::setPos(int x, int y)
```

Which allows, to move the cursor.

Is there any API for performing clicks?

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680565/qt5-c-automated-mouse-clicking it appears to be not possible...